# Set a default parameter to the first day of the month Birt report

Tags: sql, eclipse, birt

I'm creating a report in Birt report server and need to set the default Start report parameter to be the first day of current calendar month and need help.

I would really appreciate any help you can give me!

Comment: What have you tried so far that didn't work?

Comment: Trying to make changes in Eclipse Birt report manager in Report Parameters -->Edit Parameter-->Edit Default value. Eg various date parameters [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/m9QgoeP.png). Also trying to change properties on reportserver [Screenshot2](https://i.imgur.com/FowluL7.png)   So i think the solution is  to write a code in the "formula as default" field(Screenshot2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a solution. 
U need to write " ${today.firstDay()} " in specific properties-->Formula as default. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PztQn.png)

Finally u got first day of the current mounth for date_from parameter in report.

Answer (score 0):

For the first day of the month:

`SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(GETDATE())+1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DATETIME)`

If you don't want the tie tamp on it use this

`SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(GETDATE())+1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DATE)`

Comment: I need to change parameter settings right in the reportbuilder or Birt, not in SQL code.

Comment: Ok. The reporting services in your ticket is specific to SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) instead of any general reporting service. You might want to keep that in mind in the future, so you don't have to weed through answers that don't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Eclipse BIRT report manager: 
goto Variable-->new Variable-->edit default value(fx)--> and enter this code `Formatter.format(BirtDateTime.today(), "YYYY-MM-dd")` in the box---> click ok--check this 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpJ0r.png)

Now you can use this Variable in report wherever you need today's date.
You may also want to check out https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php for BIRT issues.

Hope this helps!